# Encounter std::bad_weak_ptr exception after converting a unique_ptr created from a factory method to shared_ptr and using shared_from_this

Tags: c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, factory-pattern

In summary, I have a class inherited from `std::enabled_shared_from_this`, and there is a factory method return an `std::unique_ptr` of it. In another class, I convert the `std::unique_ptr` of the previous class object to `std::shared_ptr`, and then I call `shared_from_this()`, which then throws `std::bad_weak_ptr`. The code is shown below:

```c++
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

struct Executor;
struct Executor1 {
  Executor1(const std::shared_ptr<Executor>& executor,
            int x): parent(executor) {
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
  }
  std::shared_ptr<Executor> parent;
};

struct Backend {
  virtual ~Backend() {}
  virtual void run() = 0;
};

struct Executor: public Backend, public std::enable_shared_from_this<Executor> {
  const int data = 10;
  virtual void run() override {
    Executor1 x(shared_from_this(), data);
  }
};

// std::shared_ptr<Backend> createBackend() {
std::unique_ptr<Backend> createBackend() {
  return std::make_unique<Executor>();
}

class MainInstance {
private:
  std::shared_ptr<Backend> backend;
public:
  MainInstance(): backend(createBackend()) {
    backend->run();
  }
};

int main() {
  MainInstance m;
  return 0;
}
```

Indeed changing `std::unique_ptr<Backend> createBackend()` to `std::shared_ptr<Backend> createBackend()` can solve the problem, but as I understand, in general, the factory pattern should prefer return a unique_ptr. Considering a good pratice of software engineering, is there a better solution?

Comment: The `shared_ptr` doesn't know that the `unique_ptr<Backend>` actually points to an `Executor`, and so doesn't know it's supposed to initialize the weak pointer inside `std::enable_shared_from_this<Executor>`

Answer (score 0):

> **[util.smartptr.shared.const]/1** In the constructor definitions below, enables `shared_from_this` with `p`, for a pointer `p` of type `Y*`, means that if `Y` has an unambiguous and accessible base class that is a specialization of `enable_shared_from_this` (23.11.2.5), then [magic happens that makes `shared_from_this()` work for `*p` - IT]
>
> ```
> template <class Y, class D> shared_ptr(unique_ptr<Y, D>&& r);
> ```
>
> **[util.smartptr.shared.const]/29** *Effects:* ... equivalent to shared_ptr(r.release(), r.get_deleter())...
>
> ```
> template<class Y, class D> shared_ptr(Y* p, D d);
> ```
>
> **[util.smartptr.shared.const]/10** *Effects:* ... enable `shared_from_this` with `p`

Your example executes `std::shared_ptr<Backend>(uptr)` where `uptr` is `std::unique_ptr<Backend>`, which is equivalent to `std::shared_ptr<Backend>(p, d)` where `p` is of type `Backend*`. This constructor enables `shared_from_this` with `p` - but that's a no-op, as `Backend` doesn't have an unambiguous and accessible base class that is a specialization of `enable_shared_from_this`

In order for `Executor::enable_from_this` to work, you need to pass to a `shared_ptr` constructor a pointer whose static type is `Executor*` (or some type derived therefrom).

Comment: Your answer is reasonable, but a problem remains: 
why does the code work if I change the return type of `createBackend()` from `std::unique_ptr<Backend>` to `std::shared_ptr<Backend>`?

Comment: Is this the only change you make? I imagine you also change `std::make_unique<Executor>()` to `std::make_shared<Executor>()`, whereupon you instantiate `std::shared_ptr<Executor>`. Whereas your current code never does.

Comment: Yes, you can test it on https://godbolt.org/z/4ncxhbnqj.
My code below (https://stackoverflow.com/a/71471887/8807519) also works, but I am not sure why and how `auto` works in this case...

Comment: Your original code constructs `std::shared_ptr<Backend>` from a parameter of type `std::unique_ptr<Backend>` Your modified code constructs `std::shared_ptr<Backend>` from a parameter of type `std::unique_ptr<Executor>`. This enables `shared_from_this` with pointer `p` of type `Executor*`, not of type `Backend*`.

Comment: The code in your answer works because `createBackend` now returns `std::unique_ptr<Executor>`, and that's what gets passed to `shared_ptr` constructor.

Comment: I see. Now I think inheriting `std::enable_shared_from_this` in the derived class is not a good option, so I move `std::enable_shared_from_this` to the base class (`Backend`), and then use `std::dynamic_pointer_cast` to cast the shared pointer to `Backend` to `Executor`, so that the factory pattern could return a `unique_ptr` to the base class without modifications.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I find a simple solution, that is, using `auto` as the return type of the factory function, instead of `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`, and keeping `std::make_unique` inside the factory function. The factory function `createBackend` should be:

```c++
auto createBackend() {
  return std::make_unique<Executor>();
}
```

In this case, the return type can be automatically determined, although I don't know how it works exactly. This code can return either `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`, which should be better than just using `shared_ptr`. I tested clang and gcc, and both of them worked, but I am still not sure if this is gauranteed by the type deduction and the implicit conversion.

**Update**:
Actually, I have found that `auto` deduces the return type above as `std::unique_ptr<Executor>` instead of `std::unique_ptr<Backend>`, which might be the reason why the code works. But using `auto` has an issue: if you return the smart pointer in an if-else block, where the return type varies depending on some parameters, then auto cannot determine the type. For example:

```c++
std::unique_ptr<Backend> createBackend(int k = 0) {
  if (k == 0) {
    return std::make_unique<Executor>();
  }
  else {
    return std::make_unique<Intepreter>();
  }
}
```

Here, both `Executor` and `Intepreter` derive from `Backend`. I think a correct solution includes:

1. Inherit `Backend` instead of its derived classes from `std::enable_shared_from_this`;
2. Use `dynamic_pointer_cast<Derived class>` to cast the `shared_ptr` to derived class after `shared_from_this`.

The full code is listed in:
https://gist.github.com/HanatoK/8d91a8ed71271e526d9becac0b20f758

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @OrkhanAliyev As you suggested, I have simplified and addressed the question directly as I can.